# Automatically expand margins to fill container?

Tags: html, css, margin

I've got the following HTML layout:

```
div
|-- h3
|-- ul
    |-- li
    |-- ...
    |-- li
```

The height of the `div` is fixed.  I'd like the `li`'s to fill the entire height of the div.  To manually do it, I can adjust the `margin-bottom` but this is for dynamic content, so that is out of the question.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the only way to do this is through Javascript

Comment: A couple of questions which could make the difference between having to use JS and not: Can you guarantee the text inside each `<li>` will only take one line? Do you know how many `<li>` there will be?

Comment: @thirtydot, no and no.  I mean, I can count the number of <li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using the CSS3 box layout model (flexbox), which doesn't exactly have very good support.

A pretty good tutorial can be found [here](http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/02/css3-flexible-box-layout-module-aka-flex-box-introduction-and-demostest-cases/) and a js solution to implement in older browsers can be found [here](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie) (haven't tested it myself yet, found it in the comments for the blog post above.

Edit - another tutorial [here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/)